# Arabic for Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, arabic

i am newbie to blackberry development. i got Arabic support for blackberry simulator but i couldn't install Arabic in my blackberry device.Can any one guide me to install Arabic in my blackberry phone.
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to modify your phone to allow you to type in Arabic or do you simply want to display Arabic text? It would help to know what model device you have and what OS version you are running

I came across this post the the Blackberry Support Forums: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Arabic-Font-support-in-blackberry/td-p/1540517

If you're trying to enter Arabic text, it seems that support for entering Arabic text on your device depends on your carrier and your phone. Alternatively, maybe you can try searching for "Arabic IME" in the Blackberry App World to find a third party app that lets you enter arabic text.

If you simply want to write an app that displays Arabic text then the link I provided also links to a tutorial about how to implement custom font support.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.i could install Arabic in my device successfully.This link has more guide lines http://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/archive/t-1440963.html

Comment: Well I'm sorry I couldn't have been more helpful to you.